# SQL - Redshift remove duplicate rows without primary key

Tags: sql, duplicates, amazon-redshift

I have a big redshift database.
the records do not have unique key.

I'd like to convert the below sql to postgresql.

```
DELETE FROM (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY column1, column2, column3) AS rnum
FROM tablename ) t1
WHERE t1.rnum > 1;
```

perform the above sql,the following errors appear :

> Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "(";

please :'( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can do this using `ctid`.  This is a system "column" that physically identifies each row.

The idea is:

```
delete from tablename
    where ctid not in (select min(t2.ctid)
                       from tablename t2
                       group by column1, column2, column3
                      );
```

I am not sure if Redshift supports `ctid`.  But then again, despite the tags, your question is explicitly about Postgres.

Comment: thanks answer :)!  but perform sql, following errors appear : [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column t2.ctid does not exist

Comment: redshift is based on Postgre SQL 8.0.2

Comment: @hyeyoung . . . But there are substantial differences:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html.